# ng-model on <input type='number'> dosen't allow to have characters. AngularJS, ionic

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, angular-ngmodel

I have a input which needs to trigger number keypad on a android device.As per my understanding, `type='number'` will do that for me. But I need to show a mask in the place of user's input after one second.

I'm handling this with an `ng-model`, and change the user input to mask, but it only works with `type='text'`. `type='number'` is throwing an error.

Comment: I believe the only kind of mask you can use for `type='number'` would be `*` or `-`.  what is your mask character you are trying to use?

Comment: use ui-mask and provide numeric pattern

Comment: I'm using  a &bull; to mask it with a bullet.